# Print Div Content Using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Inside AngularJs app, I want to inject generated content inside printDiv on certain on event. This `printDiv` is styled using and should be displayed on print only.

Below is the code snippet:

```
@media print {    
    body > #printDiv{
        display:block;
    }
    body > #screenContent{
        display:none;
    }        
}
@media screen {
    body > #printDiv {
        display: none;
    }
    body > #printContent{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

On certain event like (`ng-click`) like below example it calls function `GenerateContent()` on controller.

```
$scope.GenerateContent = function () {
   $("#divOne").text(data.FirstName);
   $("#divTwo").text(data.LastName);
   ...
     $scope.Print();
}
```

Here, I tried to fetch previously injected content using plain JS and then printed using `window.print()` like below:

```
$scope.Print = function () {
    var content = document.getElementById("printContent").innerHTML;            
    document.getElementById('printDiv').innerHTML = content;
    window.print();
}
```

And, finally on html page div structure is like below:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <div id="screenContent">
           // html content for screen only
       </div>
       <div id="printDiv"></div>
       <div id="printContent">
          <div id="divOne"></div>
          <div id="divTwo"></div>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

On first attempt content is generated correctly and printed well. On every other attempt content is not injected, it always prints content generated on first attempt.

Is this correct way of injecting and printing `div` using AngularJs SPA? How can my example be fixed to work in expected manner?

**Update:**

I tried with ng-bind instead of using jquery like this

```
<div id="printContent" ng-controller="myController">
    <div id="divOne" ng-bind="firstName"></div>
    <div id="divTwo" ng-bind="lastName"></div>
</div>
```

and inside controller

```
$scope.firstName = data.FirstName;
$scope.lastName = data.LastName;
```

but this doesnt inject anything into dom.

I tried also with `ng-model` instead of `ng-bind` that also doesnt work.

**Update 2**

```
myController
(function () {
    "use strict";
    app.controller('myController',
       ....
        $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: '/SomeService',
             data: ....,
           }).success(function (data) {
              $scope.firstName = data.FirstName;
              $scope.lastName = data.LastName;
          }
       });
    ...
}());
```

**Update 3**

```
<div id="printDiv">
   <div id="printContent" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
      <div id="divOne" ng-bind="data.firstName"></div>
      <div id="divTwo" ng-bind="lastName"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

myController code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.firstName: "Bob";
   $scope.lastName: "Smith";
   window.print();
});
```

I'm calling window.print to print content inside printDiv where elements are binded to controller properties, yet this not working. When I look inside firebug content is not binded at all (html structure looks ok with ng-bing, but there is no actual content binded to that element).

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Never modify the DOM directly in Angular.  Let Angular do it for you.  For example `$("#divOne").text(data.FirstName);` should just be `<div id="divOne" ng-bind="data.FirstName">` in a directive.    I suggest you work through some getting-started-with-angular tutorials, it really requires a completely different mindset from what you're used to in jQuery.

Comment: What does your controller code look like?

Comment: Re your update 3: you've got `ng-app="myApp"` but `angular.module('foo', [])` -- switch "foo" to "myApp" (or vice-versa).

Comment: ok, do you have idea why I have this behaviour, it doesnt bind anything to div from controller properties?

Comment: Because you've got syntax errors.  `$scope.firstName: "Bob";` should be `$scope.firstName="Bob";`, `$scope.lastName: "Smith";` should be `$scope.lastName ="Smith";`, and you should be watching the javascript console to catch trivial errors like that.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell from your disconnected bits and pieces where you're going off track (where is GenerateContent located relative to everything else for example?) but here is a very simple example of a controller doing what you're asking for without jQuery:

DOM:

```
<div ng-app="foo">
     <div id="printContent" ng-controller="demoController">
        <div id="divOne" ng-bind="data.firstName"></div>
        <div id="divTwo" ng-bind="data.lastName"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('foo', [])
    .controller('demoController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        firstName: "Bob",
        lastName: "Smith"
    };

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m10ojexn/

Comment: thanks Daniel, but how would you from here, after $scope.data inside controller code inject this printContent div content inside #printDiv?

Comment: The same way -- put the data on $scope and bind to it from the DOM.  It's really best to get out of the habit of thinking in terms of rummaging around directly in the DOM copying nodes here and injecting them there; angular really demands that you think in terms of modifying the underlying data and binding to it instead.

Comment: (If both printDiv and printContent are always going to contain the same html, then you'd be best off encapsulating this as a directive and embedding that directive twice.   If they need to contain the same data in different html structure, then you can bind the same bits of data to multiple DOM nodes and angular will keep track of updating them all as needed.)

Comment: I dont know what I'm doing wrong, I bind div with ng-app="myApp" and each div with corresponding property inside controller like in your code example and yet on click event this divs are not populated with wired content. I will update in a min with code example

Answer (score -3):

So injecting content using jQuery in an angular app like this isn't going to work as Angular currently has no idea that things have changed and it needs to update the UI. The quick fix for this is using Angular's `$timeout` which is setTimeout that has been modified to work in conjunction with the Angular digest cycle. Any functions that use jQuery to update the UI should be wrapped in $timeout, like this:

```
$scope.GenerateContent = function () {
  $timeout(function () {
    $("#divOne").text(data.FirstName);
    $("#divTwo").text(data.LastName);
    ...
    $scope.Print();
  }, 0);
}
```

This should cause angular to evaluate your DOM updates.
PS: Don't forget to inject $timeout into your controller.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  Any functions that use jQuery to update the UI should be rewritten to not use jQuery to update the UI.   

Seriously, if you're going to do this there's no point in using Angular in the first place.